# Cannot switch between active and in-active Angular 8

Tags: angular

So for the servcies assignment I am doing this (An assignment for an online Angular course). My user service code is

```
export class UserServicesService {

  constructor() {
    console.log(1);
  }

  users = [
    {
        name: 'Mohsin',
        active: true,
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Testaccount',
        active: true,
        id: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Hidden Account',
        active: false,
        id: 3
    }
];

  updateStatus(user: any, status: boolean) {
    this.users.filter(i => i.id === user.id)[0].active = status;

    console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

Active users

```
import { UserServicesService } from './../services/user-services.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-active-users',
  templateUrl: './active-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-users.component.scss']
})
export class ActiveUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users: any[] = [];
  constructor(private userService: UserServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  setStatus(user) {
    this.userService.updateStatus(user, false);
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.users = this.getActiveUsers();
  }

  getActiveUsers() {
    return this.userService.users.filter(i => i.active);
  }
}
```

my inactive users component is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserServicesService } from '../services/user-services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inactive-users',
  templateUrl: './inactive-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inactive-users.component.scss']
})
export class InactiveUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users: any[];
  constructor(private userService: UserServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  setStatus(user) {
    this.userService.updateStatus(user, true);
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.users = this.getInActiveUsers();
  }

  getInActiveUsers() {
    return this.userService.users.filter(i => !i.active);
  }


}
```

I have included the services in app component.

Template for active users

```
    <div *ngFor="let user of users;">
        {{user.name}}
        <button (click)="setStatus(user)">Inactivate</button>
    </div>
```

Template for inactive users

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users;">
    {{user.name}}
    <button (click)="setStatus(user)">Activate</button>
</div>
```

After updating the status it is not reflecting in my view.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ou55p6 @AdritaSharma

Answer (score 0):

instead of accessing array directly use `BehaviourSubject` in you service so your service will look like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class UserServicesService {

  constructor() {
    console.log(1);
  }
users=[
    {
        name: 'Mohsin',
        active: true,
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Testaccount',
        active: true,
        id: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Hidden Account',
        active: false,
        id: 3
    }
]
  usersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(this.users);


  getUsers(){
    return this.usersSubject.asObservable();
  }

  updateStatus(user: any, status: boolean) {
  user.active = status;
  this.usersSubject.next(this.users);
  }
}
```

then subscribe in component for example inactive component

```
init() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data=>{
    this.users = this.userService.users.filter(i => !i.active);
    })
  }
```

call init inside ngOnInit only

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuyhku)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

In the UserServicesService.updateStatus

```
this.users.filter(i => i.id === user.id)[0].active = status;
// all operations from here             ^
// are doing on the copy of the this.users array
```

According to the [How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) change

```
this.users.filter(i => i.id === user.id)[0].active = status;
```

to

```
for(const i in this.users) {
    if(this.users[i].id === user.id) {
        this.users[i].active = status;
        break;
    }
}
```